# Getting Null pointer Exception for driver under cucumber Step Definition class

Tags: java, webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am writing Step definition for Cucumber feature File and below is my code. I have initialized driver and given the path to driver in @Given ste in beginning of code, but still am getting Null pointer exception for driver on a specific line only even though whole code is using the same driver.

Below is my code :

```
public class annotation { 
 WebDriver driver = null;

  @Given("^I am on Facebook login page$")   
  public void goToFacebook() { 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation 
   Jars\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();     
 driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/"); 
  } 

 @When ("^I enter password as \"(.*)\"$") 
  public void enterPassword(String arg1) {
  System.out.println("driver= "+ driver);
  driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(arg1);
  driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_v")).click(); 
} 

  @When("^I enter username as \"(.*)\"$") 
  public void enterUsername(String arg1){     
  System.out.println("driver= "+ driver);
  driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(arg1); 
}

 @Then("^Login should fail$") 
 public void checkFail() {  
 if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(
 "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")){ 
    System.out.println("Test1 Pass"); 
 } else { 
 System.out.println("Test1 Failed"); 
} 
 driver.close(); 
}
```

Below is error I am getting :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:32)
    at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:10)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:32)
    at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(annotation\outline.feature:16)
```

But I am unable to figure out. Please help here

Comment: `findElement` can return null

Comment: Getting below in logs : annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
driver= null. Plus I don't see any reason for findElement returning null.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Can you add the feature file? Which is the line 32 in the code you have added?

Comment: Sorry for Late reply @Grasshopper, here is my feature file:

Comment: Feature: annotation 
#This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps 

Background: 
   User navigates to Facebook Given 
   I am on Facebook login page 

#Scenario with AND 
Scenario: 
   When I enter username as "TOM"
   And I enter password as "JERRY" 
   Then Login should fail 

#Scenario with BUT 
Scenario: 
   When I enter username as "TOM" 
   And I enter password as "JERRY" 
   Then Login should fail 
   But Relogin option should be available